# Cannot resolve methods 'addOnCompleteListener' and 'setonclicklistener'

Tags: android, android-studio

Here, in the following code, the methods 'addOnCompleteListener' and 'setonclicklistener' are not working. These are being shown in red colour.
SO is not allowing to post too much of code so, I am writing here all the imports that I used. OnFailureListener, OnSuccessListener, OnCompleteListener, AuthResult, FireBaseAuth.getInstance, Activity, etc. and basic imports.

```js
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView tvSignIn;
    FireBaseAuth mFireBaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFireBaseAuth = getInstance();
        emailId = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress);
        password = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button);
        tvSignIn = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailId.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();
                if (email.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Please enter the email id.");
                    emailId.requestFocus();

                } else if (!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())) {
                    mFireBaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete (Task < AuthResult > task)
                        {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,
                                        "SignUp Unsuccessful. Please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,
                            "Error Occurred!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        tvSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
            {
            public void OnClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: clean and rebuild

Comment: Restart Android Studio by clicking File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart

Comment: I tried this, but, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the you mispelled FirebaseAuth when you created an object of it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignUp;
    TextView tvSignIn;

    // THE PROBLEM IS HERE:
    FireBaseAuth mFireBaseAuth;
    /* It is miscapitalized so it doesnt know what you are talking about. There is no uppercase B in FirebaseAuth */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

So instead of

```
FireBaseAuth mFireBaseAuth;
```

Do

```
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth
```

Just a simple mistake. Trust me when I say that we all do it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. But, this is still not working. Now, there is an error in method addOnCompleteListener as well as OnFailureListener.

Comment: what is it saying?

Comment: Oh okay. Well I am sorry to say but I don't know what to tell you from here. I hope you find out a solution to your problem.

Comment: Actually, I am new to Android Studio. So, it would be really helpful if you can brief me... what basically the error is...or where should I focus on..

Comment: Okay well let me ask you. Have you added the Firebase Dependencies?  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'

Comment: You can find the dependencies in the build.gradle(Module: app) file in your studio's Gradle Scripts section. This could be the issue

Comment: Okay, when you installed Android Studio, did you make any adjustments to it whatsoever?

Comment: Nope, I didn't.

Comment: Okay you're saying that when you try to add the listeners it shows up in red? Or it wont show up at all. Please explain in detail

Comment: It shows up in red... It asks me to create a new method named (addOnCompleteListener).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind. Could you update your question and put your whole class on there including any imports that you might have. Only of you feel comfortable in doing so. The information that I have to work with is very little right now. If you could do that it could help me with solving this problem.

Comment: On top of that. Please post the version of Firebase Auth you are using.

Comment: Yeah sure... And, The Firebase Auth version is 19.3.1

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think that should work.

Comment: No problem, Muskan. Have a good day and if it helped out, please let others know that the solution worked by checking the check mark.

Comment: Yah, sure :)  You helped a lot!